# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (512,) and (256,)

Tags: python

I tried to use numpy and np.array but it fails. It displays that error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (512,) and (256,).
I dont know how to edit that code. Please help.

```
import math as mt
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

N = 512
t_min = 0   # [s]
t_max = 2   # [s]
frq = 2     # [Hz]
T_p = (t_max-t_min)/N
lst = range(0, N, 1)

t = []
sinus = []
rect = []
pila1 = []
pila2 = []

for i in lst:
    t.extend([t_min + lst[i] * T_p])
    sinus.extend([mt.sin(2 * mt.pi * frq * t[i])])
    if sinus[i] > 0:
        rect.extend([True])
    else:
        rect.extend([False])
        pila1.extend([(t[i] % (1 / frq)) * frq])
        pila2.extend([abs((t[i] % (1 / frq)) * frq - 0.5) * 2])


plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Plot')
plt.plot(t, sinus)
plt.plot(t, rect)
plt.plot(t, pila1)
plt.plot(t, pila2)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.grid(True)


plt.show()
```

there is full error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/zadanieA.py", line 32, in <module>
    plt.plot(t, pila1)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2761, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1646, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 216, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 342, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (512,) and (256,)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the full error trace so we can see what caused it. It would also be useful if you could explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: in which line no. you are getting the error. Please give complete traceback

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `t` list contains as many values as the original `lst`, as you add one item in every iteration of the loop - that gives 512 items. However, your `pila1` and `pila2` lists are extended only for positive values of `sinus[i]`, ie. half as many - so they contain only 256 items. To fix it, add items to these list as well (oh, and please do not use `extend` where `append` suffices).

```
for i in lst:
    t.append(t_min + lst[i] * T_p)
    sinus.append(mt.sin(2 * mt.pi * frq * t[i]))
    if sinus[i] > 0:
        rect.append(True)
        pila1.append(0) # or whatever value you deem "neutral"
        pila2.append(0)
    else:
        rect.append(False)
        pila1.append((t[i] % (1 / frq)) * frq)
        pila2.append(abs((t[i] % (1 / frq)) * frq - 0.5) * 2)
```

Comment: Thanks but now i have problem in line 19
`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: Check for typos.